# Using .NET to write SVG Format, what am I doing wrong with this c# implementation?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, svg

I am attempting to build a .NET add-in for Autodesk Inventor that uses the following nuget packages:

1. SVG
2. NetDXF

These libraries allow me to convert a .dxf format drawing file to an SVG format file so that (in theory) a set of them could be combined together and then thrown into http://svgnest.com to produce a nested .svg file for use with a laser/water jet/plasma cutter.

I have the following default method for creating the SVG content:

```
/// <summary>
    /// The default option because it doesn't screw up the profile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortedElements"></param>
    /// <param name="tmpSvg"></param>
    /// <param name="group"></param>
    private static void GenerateSVGPath(List<MySVGElement> sortedElements, SvgDocument tmpSvg, SvgGroup group)
    {
        try
        {
            tmpSvg.Children.Add(group);
            SvgPath startSvgpath = new SvgPath();
            //startSvgpath.Fill = SvgColourServer.None;
            startSvgpath.Visible = true;
            //svgpath.Fill = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            startSvgpath.StrokeWidth = (SvgUnit)2.0;
            startSvgpath.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            //startSvgpath.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            SvgMoveToSegment svgStartMove = new SvgMoveToSegment(new PointF
            {
                X = sortedElements[0].lineElem.StartX,
                Y = sortedElements[0].lineElem.StartY
            });
            startSvgpath.PathData.Add(svgStartMove);
            group.Children.Add(startSvgpath);
            foreach (MySVGElement item in sortedElements)
            {
                if (item.circleElem == null)
                {
                    SvgPath svgpath = new SvgPath();
                    //svgpath.Fill = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                    svgpath.Fill = SvgColourServer.None;
                    svgpath.StrokeWidth = (SvgUnit)2.0;
                    svgpath.ID = item.thisElemID;
                    svgpath.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

                    if (item.lineElem != null)
                    {
                        SvgLineSegment newline = new SvgLineSegment(item.startPoint, item.endPoint);
                        svgpath.PathData.Add(newline);
                    }
                    else if (item.arcElem != null)
                    {
                        svgpath.PathData.Add(item.arcElem);
                    }
                    group.Children.Add(svgpath);
                }
                else
                {
                    group.Children.Add(item.circleElem);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

which works just fine and produces a nicely human-readable svg file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg x="0" y="0" width="495" height="550" overflow="inherit" viewBox="-22.5, -25, 472.5, 525" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" font-size="0" xml:space="default" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
  <g xml:space="default">
    <path d="M4.028E-13 465" stroke-width="2" id="id4219e5ca-e471-440e-a668-b1b112cbd505" xml:space="default" />
    <path d="L0 500" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id51341055-7ab0-4ef3-8d9a-826329774a48" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L7.105E-13 435" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id24e3e611-5488-437d-816b-c8fc6fe6c179" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L4.8316E-12 35" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="e15c2a0f-fb81-44d1-a7c8-36d3d27c4904" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L30 465" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id3529677e-7ca6-4a10-893e-0e8c8dfa0efc" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L7.105E-13 435" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="ec5cebb8-c47a-4354-bd01-5d3346a85955" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="A15 15 180 0 1 30 465" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id7f32bf42-18af-4c1c-8855-6b9cdf94f053" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L30 65" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="b3b4baca-baa5-4fd3-ba2d-61e7d866893d" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L4.8316E-12 35" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="b527e735-9698-49c4-9117-4aa5f0a0be20" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L0 500" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id29c978ca-1ec0-4cc0-92ed-2c83a13b9370" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="A15 15 180 0 1 30 65" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id598a9a57-9ddb-4e3e-8676-e8945d21dd2d" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 465" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id6b40e290-3fb7-47b3-a202-31f9e466280d" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="A15 15 -180 0 1 420 435" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id4b00f6fc-1ccd-462d-adab-dbd976b36bf2" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 465" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id725360a4-eb90-4bc9-98da-0965274ae0c3" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L420 435" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="bd6e8c34-3323-40fa-9c19-241877b8ef1e" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 65" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id621b13da-2f10-4d9f-a894-9d586fd1ed30" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 65" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id66e3dc43-ea3c-4aac-93bd-2ca4a74efbc2" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="A15 15 -180 0 1 420 35" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="ae634d38-7a4d-4b18-80e7-eba692cc22e7" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L420 35" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="c913ab4a-ec83-4e4c-93d8-0ca277316d4b" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id30dd277c-9ea0-4b45-b3ca-e7eaafdf998b" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <path d="L450 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id1b18522e-522e-464f-857c-f7981e97e3aa" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
    <circle cx="226.2823" cy="253.5803" r="100" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" xml:space="default" style="fill:#FF0000;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The downside of this svg file is that in Google Chrome and Inkscape it doesn't produce any geometry.

It does however have the correct profile:

[image: correct profile, doesn't display in Google Chrome or Inkscape]

**The red circle is the only way I could get Chrome or Inkscape to actually display anything with the default method.**

The second method I have is very similar to the first:

```
/// <summary>
    /// the alternate option that displays in Chrome, but screws up the profile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortedElements"></param>
    /// <param name="tmpSvg"></param>
    private void GenerateSVGPath(List<MySVGElement> sortedElements, SvgDocument tmpSvg)
    {
        try
        {
            var group = new SvgGroup();
            tmpSvg.Children.Add(group);
            SvgPath svgpath = new SvgPath();
            svgpath.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            SvgMoveToSegment svgStartMove = new SvgMoveToSegment(new PointF
            {
                X = sortedElements[0].lineElem.StartX,
                Y = sortedElements[0].lineElem.StartY
            });
            svgpath.PathData.Add(svgStartMove);
            List<MySVGElement> circles = (from MySVGElement circleElem in sortedElements
                                          where circleElem.circleElem != null
                                          select circleElem).ToList();

            svgpath.Visible = true;
            svgpath.Fill = SvgColourServer.None;
            svgpath.StrokeWidth = (SvgUnit)2.0;
            svgpath.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            foreach (var item in sortedElements)
            {
                if(item.circleElem == null)
                {
                    if (item.lineElem != null)
                    {
                        SvgLineSegment newline = new SvgLineSegment(item.startPoint, item.endPoint);
                        svgpath.PathData.Add(newline);
                    }
                    else if (item.arcElem != null)
                    {
                        svgpath.PathData.Add(item.arcElem);
                    }
                }
            }
            group.Children.Add(svgpath);
            if(circles.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in circles)
                {
                    group.Children.Add(item.circleElem);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

This method also works correctly and produces the following svg content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg x="0" y="0" width="495" height="550" overflow="inherit" viewBox="-22.5, -25, 472.5, 525" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" font-size="0" xml:space="default" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
  <g xml:space="default">
    <path d="M4.028E-13 465 L0 500 L7.105E-13 435 L4.8316E-12 35 L30 465 L7.105E-13 435 A15 15 180 0 1 30 465 L30 65 L4.8316E-12 35 L0 500 A15 15 180 0 1 30 65 L450 465 A15 15 -180 0 1 420 435 L450 465 L420 435 L450 65 L450 65 A15 15 -180 0 1 420 35 L420 35 L450 0 L450 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="id01a8da76-20f9-405f-aa2b-487be02120ea" xml:space="default" style="fill:none;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Which does display correctly inside of Google Chrome & Inkscape. The downside is that the profile gets screwed up in the process:

[image: Displays inside both Google Chrome & Inkscape with a broken profile]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? The SVG library is very good, but there is very little documentation available within/on it.

The really odd thing is that according to the [W3C Validator website](https://validator.w3.org/), both of these files contain valid SVG code.

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Autodesk of DXF files, but it looks like each line segment has a start point and an endpoint.  Your code seems to be assuming that each start point matches the end point of the last segment.  Try checking that in your loop, and if they don't, start a new path element (with an M).

Comment: Hi @PaulLeBeau, that's the thing; in the first method the points are all continuous having been sorted in a clockwise fashion and if you look at the first image the path is correct. the problem is, neither Google Chrome or Inkscape displays that continuous path, favouring instead the path generated by the bottom image.

Comment: The first method has invalid path elements. All path descriptions should start with a move (M or m). `d="d="L0 500"` is not a valid path description.

Comment: Seeing you say that, it makes perfect sense; I suppose it's a limitation of the SVG library I used as it's perfectly happy creating a profile with the afore-mentioned incorrect syntax. Thanks!